# R package kernlab installation issue

Tags: r, centos, elf, kernlab

I am facing issues while installing the kernlab R package on CentOS using the following command:

```
install.packages("/home/R_Libraries/kernlab_0.9-20.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object     '/opt/vertica/R/library/kernlab/libs/kernlab.so':
  libgfortran.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

gfortran is installed as confirmed by the following command:

```
ldconfig -v|grep fortran

libgfortran.so.1 -> libgfortran.so.1.0.0
```

Can someone help with fixing this issue?

Comment: Sure, it is not just "install.packages("kernlab")" (and your options)? Did you try it in RStudio or via the console? You can also try it via "Tools"->"install packages" in RStudio.

Comment: The CentOS machine I am using doesn't have internet access. So I have to install the package from the source.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
 libgfortran.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

means that you've tried to load 32-bit `libgfortran` into a 64-bit program.

Unfortunately you didn't tell us anything that would allow us to help you. Not even where this `libgfortran` is coming from.

You should make sure that a 64-bit `libgfortran` is installed in the system location, and the above error would go away.